# Cómo puedo asociar un vector con un botón?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Soy nuevo en PHP, quisiera saber como puedo hacer esto, o alguna sugerencia que sea diferente código, pero mismo resultado.

Este es La parte de mi código:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="a" Value="b" >
</form>

<?php

$id= $row['ID'];    
  if(isset($_POST[''])){ //
    mysqli_query($Link,"UPDATE baseusuarios SET permiso ='0' where ID = '$id'" );
    header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Quiero hacer que en cada `TABLE DATE` se cree un botón con un número asignado, y que al apretarle cambie en mi base de datos el dato "1" al dato "0".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera poner un `for` o `While` en el `name` o `value` de mi `submit`, he intentado pero al darle clic al botón TODOS LAS COLUMNAS DE "Permiso" en mi DB se cambian a 0.

Adjunto una imagen de perspectiva de mi página. Sólo préstenle atención a la última columna 'opción', porfavor.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, lo que quieres hacer es cambiar los permisos desde un boton. Tambien puede hacerlo desde una etiqueta `a` si quieres y te quedaria algo asi: `<a href="update.php?id=<?=$row['ID'];?>">Cambiar a cliente</a>` y dentro del update.php tomas el `id` y haces la modificacion.

Comment: Te falta el nombre de campo en: `if(isset($_POST[''])){`

Answer (score 0):

como estás?

En el código te falta el campo id, ya que si bien lo quieres obtener dentro del código PHP al hacer: $id= $row['ID'], éste no está presente en el formulario.
De todas formas, aunque estuviese presente, cada vez que presiones el botòn te refrescaría la pantalla.
Esto lo puedes solucionar utilizando ajax, para darle al usuario una expriencia mejor de uso.
Fijate en: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Espero te sirva!!